# Registering iOS device for Push Notifications using Parse and Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, iphone, parse-platform, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm having trouble registering my iOS device with Parse Push while using Xamarin.iOS.  I can manually register my device using the Parse REST API curl command and can receive push notifications. However my application/device cannot register on its own when it is running.

I followed this tutorial, following the steps several times from start to finish - https://www.parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications

In my Xamarin App I have the proper implementation as based on the Parse code sample provided here - https://github.com/ParsePlatform/PushTutorial/blob/master/Xamarin/ParseXamarinPushSample/AppDelegate.cs

Everything builds, compiles and deploys just fine.  At some point RegisteredForRemoteNotifications is called and I am able to debug output my device token to the console.

In order for me to manually register my device I take this token as well as my other keys and issue the following curl command:

```
curl -X POST \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: <Your Parse app ID> " \
-H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: <Your parse REST API key>" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{
    "deviceType": "ios",
    "deviceToken": "<Your device token>",
    "channels": [
      ""
    ]
  }' \
https://api.parse.com/1/installations
```

And it is only at this point that I see my device registered in the Parse Push portal.  At this point I can send push notifications and receive them.  If I uninstall the app and re-deploy then of course my device token is new and I have to re-issue the curl command to register this device, not very practical on a large scale.

What could possibly be going wrong?

To recap:

1) I can receive push notifications if I manually issue the REST API curl command with my device token that I receive while running debug code in RegisteredForRemoteNotifications.

2) I've followed the Parse tutorial with creating certificates etc. and everything indicates valid on the Apple Developer portal.  I am signing my app with the proper provisioning profile and the info.plist file reflects the correct Bundle Identifier and it is configured with "Enable Background Modes" and "Remote Notifications" within the Background Modes section of Info.plist.

3) I simulated the "24 hour of application uninstall" that Apple indicates may be a culprit.  I uninstalled the app, set the date to 25 hours ahead of time on my iPhone, shutdown my phone and started it back up and installed.

Side note - I found a similar issue but it does not appear to be tagged with parse.com so I'm hoping this properly tagged question will get the help of the parse and xamarin community.  That stack overflow question is here - [No Devices Registered with Parse Push and Xamarin IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33041335/no-devices-registered-with-parse-push-and-xamarin-ios)

Update: So I finally got my device to register but going a totally different way.  Here's what my RegisteredForRemoteNotifications looks like now. (Note: *I am using Parse 1.5.5 as newer versions did not work at the time of this writing.  Currently the newest version is 1.6.2.*)

```
public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken) {
        ParseObject obj = ParseObject.Create ("_Installation");

        string dt = deviceToken.ToString ().Replace ("<", "").Replace (">", "").Replace (" ", "");
        obj["deviceToken"] = dt;
        obj.SaveAsync ().ContinueWith (t => {
            if (t.IsFaulted) {
                using (IEnumerator<System.Exception> enumerator = t.Exception.InnerExceptions.GetEnumerator()) {
                    if (enumerator.MoveNext()) {
                        ParseException error = (ParseException) enumerator.Current;
                        Console.WriteLine ("ERROR!!!: " + error.Message);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Console.WriteLine("Saved/Retrieved Installation");
                var data = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults;
                data.SetString ("currentInstallation", obj.ObjectId);
                Console.WriteLine("Installation ID = " + obj.ObjectId);
            }
        });
    }
```

I'd still like to know why we can't do

```
public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken) {
  ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.CurrentInstallation;
  installation.SetDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken);

  installation.SaveAsync();
}
```

But for now I have something that works.